# How to use the php file_exist

Tags: php

I have been trying to get a way to display an error like "File already exist" if the uploads folder has such file. This is to help prevent duplicated files. I try using the php file_exists() but it dose not produce an error. Instead it skips right to file uploaded. However, it dose not upload the file, so no duplicate is created. But, it don't display the error file already exist, either. No way of letting the user who is uploading the file knows that a file with that name already exist. Below is the php file upload script. Thanks for any help on this one.

```
<?php

  //echo "Hello world from PHP Ajax test file";

   if(isset($_POST['show'])){
    //$file = $_FILES['file'];
    print_r($_FILES['file']);
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];

    $fileAllowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'txt', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'js', 'pdf', 'svg');

    $ext = explode('.', $fileName);
    $newExt = end($ext);
    $lowerCaseExt = strtolower($newExt);
    $fileNewName = $fileName . '.' . $lowerCaseExt;

    $fileDestination = 'uploads/' . $fileNewName;

    if(!in_array($lowerCaseExt, $fileAllowed)){
        echo '<br>File type not allowed';
        exit();
    }

    if($fileSize > 1000000){
        echo '<br>File is to large';
        exit();
    }


    if($fileError > 0 && file_exists($fileDestination)){
            echo "<br>File already exist";
            exit();
    }else{
        move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);
        echo "<br>Your files was uploaded";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have multiple issues here.

1. `file_exists` returns a boolean, not an integer -> the greater than `1` comparison does not make sense
2. you spelled it wrong and made it a variable `$file_esxit`
3. you only exit out if an error occured **and** the filename already exists
4. you are using `pathinfo` on the filename within the `file_exist` which doesn't make sense to me
5. you are not using `pathinfo` on the original name, but manually split the name resulting in *example.JPG* being called *example.JPG.jpg*. I don't think you actually want that.
6. you are using `move_uploaded_file` with a destination that is partly controllable by the user, which is dangerous
7. you are assuming the same name means the same file and vice versa

Maybe some of this helps you fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The error was the typo file_exist. The correct thing is file_exists($fileDestination). It works like it should now. I have looked at it so many times and did not see the typo.  I have removed the pathinfo, I only put that in to see if it was going to help. Tired eyes I guess.

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend using an editor with hinting for PHP; that way you can focus more on the important stuff.

Comment: I use VS code but there are a lot of extentions you have to add for PHP. I will find a PHP extention that can highlignt typos and errors.

Comment: PHP file_exist checks to see if a file was already uploaded and prevents a duplicate. Anything you do with this function should be based on preventing a file duplicate.

Comment: @falcon file_exists checks if a file exists on a given location. It has nothing to do with file duplicates. Please note point 6 of my answer. Also you won't get the desired result because of point 3 `if($fileError > 0 && file_exists($fileDestination))`; this should be two checks. If the file exists, but no upload error occured the condition is `false` thus the file should still be overwritten.